# How to style list and paragraph next to icon?

Tags: html, css, html-table

This is what I am trying to achieve:

[image: SCREEN]

I am using table, because I have multiple of cells like this. What I need is :

- Paragraph(Procesor) aligned next to icon
- Unordered list aligned under paragraph and next to icon
- Line aligned to bottom of cell
- Same size of cells

So far I have:

```
<td width="275" height="140" class="bottom">
    <img src="http://imagehost.cz/images/1h636n4fs7e57jqrwk9.png" />
    <p>Procesor</p>
    <ul>
        <li>Description</li>
    </ul>
    <img src="http://imagehost.cz/images/kuovfjbxatq5vovthqje.png" id="line"/>
</td>
```

And CSS is:

```
.bottom {vertical-align: bottom;}
#line {display: block;margin: auto;}
```

I know this is probably some noobie mistake, but I am new to this, and I am learning through
trial-and-error.

Comment: What browser support are you looking for? If you don't need old IE too much, flexbox does an excellent job at this.

Comment: I don't see anything in that image that can be reproduced using divs and floats.

Comment: I still don't understand why you are using a table

Comment: Here is one overly complicated solution, which allows you to have different children after the image which all will be aligned... No Table though. http://jsfiddle.net/u2C74/1/

Comment: Cuz in final version, it should look like this - http://i.imgur.com/55lSmKY.jpg

Answer (score 3):

Have updated your code. Try with this.
[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4fkVe/)

```
.bottom {
background:#f9f9f9;
padding:10px;
width:275px;
display:block;
min-height:140px;
border-bottom:2px solid #000;
}
#line{
display:block;
margin:auto;
}
img{
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:middle;
}
p{
display:inline-block;
margin:0;
}
ul{
display:block;
margin: 5px 0 10px 10px;
font-size:12px;
color:#333;
font-family:Arial;
}
```

Comment: Great answer, works pretty well... but it seems like they are stacking vertically, and not being in 3 columns like i had planned. What is solution to that ? Final version should look like :  i.imgur.com/55lSmKY.jpg

Answer (score 0):

use this css

```
.bottom,img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
p{
    display:inline-block;
}
#line {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
```